# Can't get cascaded validations working on Grails 2.0.4

Tags: validation, grails

I have the following domain entities:

```
class Customer {

   // Customer properties...

   static belongsTo [user: User]
}

class User {

   // User properties...

}
```

When i try to validate a `Customer` instance that includes a `User` instance with errors, validation succeeds. In my unit test:

```
Customer customer = new Customer()
// Set customer properties...

User user = new User()
// Set user properties that contain errors...

customer.user =  user

assertFalse user.validate()     // succeeds
assertFalse customer.validate() // fails!
```

The same behaviour is observed on the runtime application as well. I have run my application in debug mode and verified that user's errors property is null.

I have also tried invoking validate(deepValidate:true) on my customer instance (which according to the documentation is the default setting anyway), with no success.

Any tips?

Comment: Does Grails allow yoou to save the `customer` ?

Comment: What relationship is User to Customer? hasOne, hasMany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why grails will not cascade validations to nested objects by default, or at least why it doesn't work in my example.

However, i found the following workaround which works for me. In the parent class i define the following validator:

```
class Customer {

  static belongsTo = [user:User]

  static constraints {
    user: nullable: false, validator: {it?.validate()}
  }
}
```

When validate() is invoked on a Customer instance, the associated User is also validated.